# Tkinter print multiple lambda's

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to learn how I can output/join multiple lambda's to a label.

I want to output the file type the user selects as well as the upload date.
Here is the code I have come up with but it doesn't "get" anything.

```
output_path = ttk.Label(tab1, text="Output Path: " +file_type_selected.get())
output_path.grid(column=0, row=6)
```

Here is the code that will print what the user has entered.

```
file_selected_label = ttk.Label(tab1)
file_type_selected.trace_add('write', lambda *args:file_selected_label.config(text="" +file_type_selected.get()))
file_selected_label.grid(column=3, row=4, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)
```

So I want the output to be Output Path: FILE NAME.DATE UPLOADED

Comment: Uhm, how do you get the file name? And the date? You showed us the `file_type_selected`, what does it give

Comment: This is not a good use of `lambda`. Write a proper function and maybe the solution will be easier for you to see, and it will certainly be easier to debug.